# iPad app... Which site am I on?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, ios-app, ipad

In the iPad app, I see small icons on the left bar to show which SE site I'm on.... Useful, apart from the fact I'm a fairly casual SE user and don't know what half the sites are, never mind what the logo looks like.

A text indicator would be helpful, either in a ? Or info option in the 'sub-icons' that appear under each site's icon, or in the title when viewing the individual site.

Hopefully I'm posting this in the right place, but the fact I'm not 100% sure I'm on meta, probably says it all.

Comment: This is the right place; you can relax. :)

Answer (score 1):

We had added the site names in the title of many screens, but a bug prevented this from showing in most of them. It was only appearing when you opened questions from the feed:

[image]

This will be fixed in the beta **version 1.1.0.126**.

In addition, if you ever want to see all the site names at a glance, you can tap on the hamburger icon, which will expand the menu to its full size:

[image]

Comment: Good news on the fix, and I can indeed see the site now I'm in a question.... The hamburger doesn't show up while in a question, though, so I didn't see it - not a deal breaker, but could perhaps be more intuitive?

Comment: @JonStory yes, I am thinking about adding a gesture to the navigation bar to make it possible to open the menu at all times